# Number of $2$-colorings of $m\times n$ rectangular grid up to symmetry where each edge row and column has white cell

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Find a number of ways to color cells of rectangular $4\times 6$ grid ($24$ cells) with $2$ colors (black and white) up to rotations and reflections given that each edge (border row and column) has at least one white cell.

My plan:

1. Apply Polya's enumeration principle to find number of colorings whithout constrains on edge cells.
   Number of distinct colorings up to symmetry is equal to number of orbits of $G\curvearrowright \operatorname{Map}(X,C)$, which by Burnside's lemma is equal to $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\operatorname{Fix}_{\operatorname{Map}(X,C)}(g)| = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|C|^{c(g)}$, where $G$ - symmetry group of rectangle, $g\in G$, $c(g)$ - number of cycles of permutation $g$, $C$ - set of colors.
2. Figure out how to solve simplified version of initial problem
    `Find a number of colorings up to symmetry where first row has no white cells.`
   Using this result we can find number of "incorrect" colorings with no white cells in each
   subset of edges.
3. Apply inclusion-exclusion principle and results from steps 1 and 2 to solve the initial problem.

---

Steps 1 and 3 seem quite clear to me, but I struggle with step 2.

Strategy from step 1 does not seem to be directly applicable to the case with black-colored first row. Indeed set of colorings: $S = \{\phi \in \operatorname{Map}(X,C) : \phi(x) = \text{black } \forall x \in \text{first row} \}$, it is not closed under $G$, $G\curvearrowright S$ is not defined.

Does there exist a common way of solving such colorings-counting problems with pre-assigned colors?